# AngularJS ui-grid- To show 'No Data Available' when the response contains empty array

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I want to show '**No Data Available**' in ui-Grid 3.0, if the response from the ajax contains empty json data array i.e.;

```
data = {"data": []};
```

And now if i do -

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = data.data;
```

'No Data Available' must come in ui-Grid.

What is currently happening is that user gets a blank screen if data is empty.

Also how to make it as a default functionality ?

See the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UKqO1jskJ6SzEnsD0I4J?p=preview) here.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use a "watermark" ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QSIhiQk26VR7LeAvpHbc?p=preview)) ([updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YzoYv1pghNYtGR9tDTM4?p=preview))

**template**

```
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter class="grid">
    <div class="watermark" ng-show="!gridOptions.data.length">No data available</div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    top : 80px;
    opacity: 0.25;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

**Edit:**

to make the .watermark independent from the specific parent size:

```
.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;                    <---- Center vertically in the parent element,
    transform: translateY(-50%); <---- it works for any parent height
    opacity: 0.25;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me a lot of time!!
Updated the plunker with your solution.

Comment: if I want to apply this watermark to the row data which is empty,how can i add this class at that row (box).

Comment: Man you are awesome

Comment: I used your solution, its good, but I have api calls which will take some time so this no data available will start showing while api is processing, any solution for this? to hide that msg initially?

Comment: @Sudarshan you could define a variable on the controller scope `api_done` and `ng-show="api_done && !gridOptions.data.length"`